# Why suddenly the slave node lost connection to the master node in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, networking, hadoop2

I have set up hadoop 2.7.2 upon a cluster with a master(ubuntu 15.10) and two slave(slave2,3) hosted in the master by virtualbox.

I have run several examples like wordcount,it all works ok. But when i try to run my own job,say Myjob, it runs well at first, but after a while, it will definitely be interrupted by this error:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:      slave3/xxx.216.227.176(the ip of slave):38046. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Sometimes it would be slave2 ,sometimes would be slave3. And my connection to that slave by ssh shows that `the connection is closed by remote`.

But the virtualbox shows that slave runs well, and i can ressh to that slave, **However all the hadoop process are been killed**.
Need to mention that my own job runs longer than the example job.

At first, i think it maybe some error caused by my config file, so, i reinstall hadoop at master and slaves. But the error stills.

So, i think that maybe it is caused by my network config in the slave nodes. So, i changed the last filed of the slave's ip like `xxx.xxx.xxx.183 to xxx.xxx.xxx.176` and reinstall hadoop.

And I rerun the job, at this time the job runs longer than usual. But, at the last, when the map stage mostly finished (`map 86% reduce 28%`), it failed due to the same error!

`INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server:    slave3/125.xxx.227.xxx(the ip of slave):38046. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)`

Also there is something log in `yarn-user-resourcemanager-Master.log` :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Call From Master/xxx.216.227.186 to slave2:44592 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: refuse to connect; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

**It seems like that the longer time the app runs , the bigger chance it will fail.**

Here is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost                                                                                                                                                                                           
#127.0.1.1      Master
xxx.216.227.186 Master                                                                                                                                                                                              
xxx.216.227.185 slave1# the slave1 has some problem thus do not connect to the cluster                                                                                                                                                                                       
xxx.216.227.176 slave2                                                                                                                                                                                              
xxx.216.227.166 slave3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts                                                                                                                                                          
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback                                                                                                                                                                                  
fe00::0 ip6-localnet                                                                                                                                                                                                
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix                                                                                                                                                                                             
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes                                                                                                                                                                                                
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Why? How to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to post the log content for the slave nodes that is going down. They are usually present in the `/var/log/hadoop`.

Comment: There is not such a file in `/var/log`. But i can find some thing in the log in `yarn-user-resourcemanagement-Master.log` :    `java.net.ConnectException: Call From Master/xxx.216.227.186 to slave2:44592 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: refuse to connect; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused  `

Comment: You mention that certain things work ok (like wordcount).  If you run a wordcount now, will it run succesfully AND use both slaves? Because from your description it is unclear whether the slaves sometimes work, or always fail.

Comment: Sometimes it works ok, but sometimes it fail due to the same error that slave fails.

Comment: Go to the hadoop configuration (usually it is `/etc/hadoop/conf`), there you will find the whole hadoop system configuration files. Open the file by name `hadoop-env.sh`, inside that file search for `HADOOP_LOG_DIR`. Get the value it is set to. It is there the logs are logged. Now if the variable is left empty give some directory where it can log. This time when the error occurs it will log it there. Then post the log content here. Without it, not possible to help.

Comment: The log file logs nothing but the `retrying connect to server` message and `connection exception` shows above. It seems like that the longer time the app runs , the bigger chance it will fail.